# How does a cracker know if they've broken AES-CBC encryption?

Tags: encryption, cbc, brute-force-attack

How does a cracker know if they've broken CBC or stream encryption? With hashe cracking one would know because you have the password that you started with to test. But for CBC decryption, you have a 16 bit block (AES), a key, and an IV. With the wrong key one will get random data as output. So how will one know when the right key was found? The output may be binary so how is it determined if the decryption was a success? Does the attacker require knowledge of the type of contents, to search for magic numbers or headers?